# Exiting a program that is called in my script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that basically calls/executes another program, sleeps 5 seconds, kills the said program, sleeps again for 5 seconds before ultimately restarting the whole cycle.

Here's my attempt of creating the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do

someOtherProgram -options..etc.
PID=$!
echo "someOtherProgram initiated"
sleep 5
kill $PID
echo "someOtherProgram killed"
sleep 5
echo "restarting loop"

done
```

With this script, it's able to start `someOtherProgram` but it gets stuck there. I don't even see my echo `"someOtherProgram initiated"` printed on the terminal.

I know this is an easy-fix but I'm not well versed with bash scripting as I just started.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `$!`,

```
"Expands to the process ID of the job most recently 
 placed into the background"
```

You are not backgrounding `someOtherProgram -options..etc.`. To do so, you would need:

```
someOtherProgram -options..etc. &
```

(note: the ampersand `&` at the end)

Currently your `PID` is empty. You can easily confirm this for yourself by attempting to output it, e.g.

```
echo "someOtherProgram initiated (PID: $PID)"
```

You can find detailed explanations for both the use of `$!` and backgrouding processes (running asynchronously) under the `"Special Parameters"` and `"JOB CONTROL"` sections within `man bash`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the helpful information. I got it working now!

Comment: Good deal. Keep at it. There is literally nothing you can't do with bash (within reason). It is as awesome shell.

Answer (score 0):

[*Rankin's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053406/6136214) is the correct one, as it shows why the code failed.  Still, if another method is needed, there's the `timeout` command, which is sometimes more convenient as it avoids needing to keep track of a variable.  Here's what the loop looks like:

```
while true
do
    ( timeout 5 someOtherProgram -options..etc. &
      echo "someOtherProgram initiated"
      wait ; )
    echo "someOtherProgram killed"
    sleep 5
    echo "restarting loop"
done
```

Unfortunately that code is less efficient than using variables, especially since it uses shell parentheses `()` and a `wait`.  If the *initialize* message was printed first, it'd be simpler:

```
while true
do
    echo "someOtherProgram initializing..."
    timeout 5 someOtherProgram -options..etc.
    echo "someOtherProgram killed"
    sleep 5
    echo "restarting loop"
done
```